# In python is there a way to delete parts of a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to trim the values of a pandas data frame. For example, I have the following:

```
 A            B        C
 33344-10   5555-78  999902
 3444441    5555679  2334
 2334       5555     3344
```

And I would like the result to be:

```
A            B         C
3334       5555     9999
3444       5555     2334
2334       5555     3344
```

If anyone could help it would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are all your values strings? `33344-10` is a string, right?

Comment: yeah they should be strings, I was thinking of using regex but I don't know how to do it for this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To keep first 4 characters in string columns:

```
for c in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
    df[c] = df[c].str.slice(stop=4)
```

Comment: Why are you looping? `df[['A', 'B', 'C']].str.slice(stop=4)` would work as well right?

Comment: no, it would not. `str` is a property of Column not of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 5):

slice each column in a loop as below

```py
columns = df.columns
for column in columns:
    df[column] = df[column].astype(str).str[:4]
df
```

which gives you the following output

```
    A   B   C
0   3334    5555    9999
1   3444    5555    2334
2   2334    5555    3344
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DateFrame.applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html):

```
new_df = df.applymap(lambda s: str(s)[:4])
```

The `str` takes care of those values which are not strings (e.g. `int`).

Comment: When i do this it returns this error 'Series' object has no attribute 'applymap'

Comment: `df` has to be the whole `pandas.DataFrame`.